# shared_ptr and private inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, shared-ptr

Here's a toy example illustrating a problem I encounter. The application is fairly irrelevant (it's essentially a linked list of elements with a special behavior at the end).  I'm unable to construct a base class shared_ptr with a derived pointer and it's for some reason linked to the fact that I'm using private inheritance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

using namespace std;

// An Item in a linked list
class A
{
public:
  //friend class B;
  typedef boost::shared_ptr<A> APtr;
  A() : next_() {}
  A(APtr n) : next_(n) {}
  APtr next() { return next_; }
  void setNext(APtr n) { next_ = n; }

  virtual void doIt() { /* standard behavior */ }  

private:
  APtr next_;
};


class B : private A // B really is a special A
                    // that should have different behavior
                    // at the tail of the chain
                    // but I want to hide A's interface
                    // to external clients
{
public:
  typedef boost::shared_ptr<B> BPtr;
  B(A::APtr prev) 
  { // Set this object as the tail
    prev->setNext(APtr(this));  /* WHY CAN'T I CONSTRUCT APtr(this) 
                                   WITH PRIVATE INH. */
  }
  void doIt() {/*special behavior at end */}

};

int main()
{
  A::APtr dummyPtr;
  A::APtr head = boost::make_shared<A>(dummyPtr);
  B::BPtr tail = boost::make_shared<B>(head);

  for(A::APtr curr = head; curr; curr=curr->next()){
    curr->doIt();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

and I get this

```
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp: In constructor ‘boost::shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr(Y*) [with Y = B, T = A]’:
derived_shared.cpp:31:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:352: error: ‘A’ is an inaccessible base of ‘B’
```

I was under the impression that private inheritance allows the Derived class to still access the public interface of the base class but hides that interface to external clients.  Why does private inheritance cause this error (it works if I inherit publicly)?

Comment: You should read this page
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance

Comment: friend boost::shared_ptr, but your design is flawed (passing the address of a non dynamically allocated B)

Comment: You should have a look at [enable_shared_from_this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/smart_ptr/enable_shared_from_this.html).

Comment: @DieterLücking yes, you are right...that was just an oversight in my toy example...sorry.  so I'd make boost::shared_ptr a friend of B  or A?

Comment: @RobertJacobs thank you for your help but can you be more specific as to what portion I should refer to, I feel like I've read through that and understand the concepts of public, private, and protected inheritance. I'm not seeing where I'm going wrong...

Comment: @innocent_bystander of none - redesign.

Comment: then what was your intent with the comment:  'friend boost::shared_ptr'

Comment: @RobertJacobs I guess what I'm saying is that this would work if I used raw pointers

Comment: @DieterLücking wait, B is dynamically allocated isn't it (make_shared??)...what's the flaw?

Comment: @innocent_bystander what Dieter means, is that (if inhteritance would be public) head is known as shared_ptr<A> AND as shared_ptr<B>, 2 different shared pointers.  When leaving main, both reference count go to 0 and and attempt is made to delete the object twice.  The same raw pointer should not be used to create shared pointers of different types.

Comment: Just as a comment, the standard library now include [`shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) and [`make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared).

Answer (score 5):

Change this single line:

```
prev->setNext(APtr(this));
```

to

```
prev->setNext(APtr(static_cast<A*>(this)));
```

And it compiles.

Or at least it does when using the `std` library. It is usually similar for `boost`.

There are other errors but that gets round casting `B*` to `A*`.

Why does that work? Because the template for the constructor `std::shared_ptr<A>` isn't what you think it is! It is more like `template <class X> std::shared_ptr(X* v)`. So the actual `B*` to `A*` cast is postponed and failing in a non-friend member.

But if you cast the `B*` pointer (i.e. `this`) to `A*` inside a method of `class B` (the only place that is legal without a `friend` declaration) you're in.

**NB:** There is nothing in principle wrong with private inheritance. It isn't an anti-pattern and is provided for good reason. Do think about composition but objects that forbid some parts of the application from 'accessing' their 'real' type have lots of uses. For example pass out an object A that has some B bolt ons that only the object factory can access.

**PS:** The reason why the constructor is `template<class T> shared_ptr<T* v>` is so that `shared_ptr` uses the deleter of the type passed into it.
As you're not doubt aware `share_ptr` cleverly calls the 'right' destructor even if it isn't virtual.
My 'fix' actually subverts that cleverness so beware to pass in the right deleter or (recommended) make the destructor of `A` virtual.

PPS:

And finally a fully working program (using STL. Sorry I don't have Boost):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

// An Item in a linked list
class A
{
public:
  //friend class B;
  typedef std::shared_ptr<A> APtr;
  A() : next_() {}
  A(APtr n) : next_(n) {}
  APtr next() { return next_; }
  void setNext(APtr n) { next_ = n;}

  virtual void doIt() { std::cout<<"normal thing"<<std::endl; }  

  virtual ~A(){}
private:
  APtr next_;
};

class B : public std::enable_shared_from_this<A>, private A // B really is a special A
                    // that should have different behavior
                    // at the tail of the chain
                    // but I want to hide A's interface
                    // to external clients
{
public:
  template<class X> friend class std::enable_shared_from_this;

  typedef std::shared_ptr<B> BPtr;


  static BPtr makeit(A::APtr prev){
    BPtr B(std::make_shared<B>());
    prev->setNext(B->shared_from_this());
    return B;
  } 

  void doIt() {std::cout<<"end thing"<<std::endl;}
private: 
  B(){}
};

int main()
{
  A::APtr dummyPtr;
  A::APtr head = std::make_shared<A>(dummyPtr);
  B::BPtr tail = B::makeit(head);

  for(A::APtr curr = head; curr; curr=curr->next()){
    curr->doIt();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

You need to use `enable_shared_from_this` because otherwise you're trying to create two 'families' of `shared_ptr` and that won't work.

I've made a factory method because fixing the constructor just wouldn't work!
There is a precondition of `enable_shared_from_this` that there has to be a `std::shared_ptr` in existence and I suppose that means 'fully constructed'.

The following constructor will not work for me:

```
B(A::APtr prev){
   prev->setNext(shared_from_this());
}
```

That said, if you do inherit from `enable_shared_from_this` it's a good idea to make all the constructors private and provide factories that return `shared_ptr`. Otherwise you can get in a right mess if calling code doesn't itself ensure that 'pre-existing `shared_ptr`' condition. A nasty piece of coupling if ever there was one.

Answer (score 2):

When you use private inheritance, you're basically saying "I want B to be implemented in terms of A, but I don't want it to be used like a A (is-a A)"

Here, you're giving `boost::shared_ptr` a pointer to B as if it was an A.

That's a contradiction in your design. Maybe declaring `boost::shared_ptr<A>` a friend of B would help, but it's still a weird design.

Additional note: If you want B to be a special A that doesn't expose A's interface, consider composition instead of private inheritance

Comment: Well that's a first thought.  However, if you make it protected inheritance, you get the same resutlt.  Should'nt members of a class get access to the protected base ?

Comment: @Christophe `shared_ptr<A>` is a type completely separate from `B`. If `B` protectedly inherits from `A`, then all the children of `B` will also inherit from `A`, but a separate type like `shared_ptr<A>` won't know that (unless you make it a friend).

Comment: Okay thanks...I guess I am just a bit confused because if you use raw pointers (A* and B*) everything compiles (i.e. I can do prev->next(this) ).  I undestand that since shared_ptr<A> is a different object that it doesn't have access to the A constructor.  But this then is a non-transparent difference between raw pointer capability and shared_ptr<> [said w/ no judgement...just noting it]

Comment: @innocent_bystander `shared_ptr` doesn't get any special treatment, it's a regular citizen. `shared_ptr<A>` has nothing to do with `A`, same as `vector<int>` has nothing to do with `int`. Casting the `B* this` to an `A*` only works in `B::B()`. If you were to do that anywhere else (i.e. in a non-friend of `B`), say in `main()` or `shared_ptr<B>`, it wouldn't work.